# python csv read column function not giving correct output

Tags: python

I am trying to read a single column in my csv data file with the following function, however when I run the function it only prints out the header instead of the whole column.

I want the function to print out a single column from my csv file (including the heading) in the form of a list.

I am very confused about where I am going wrong and would be very appreciative for any help.

thank you in advance for your response.

```
def read_column(filename, column:int):
    file = open ('data1.csv', 'r')
    for rows in csv_file:
        column = (rows.split(',')[0])
        return column
```

Comment: your question says ```prints``` but in your function you are returning. please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Please enter the values in the list and return the list:

```
def read_column(filename, column:int):
    file = open ('data1.csv', 'r')
    list=[]
    for rows in csv_file:
        column = (rows.split(',')[0])
        list.append(column)
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

in your loop function you return only the first line you read.

So, if you want to get all the lines. Instead of return `column` at the first time you read it. You should store the value and return all the stored value at once.

```
def read_column(filename):
    file = open (filename, 'r')
    allLines = []
    for rows in csv_file:
        column = rows.split()
        allLines.append(column)
    
    # return all at once after read all lines.
    return allLines

print(read_column('data1.csv'))
```

Comment: thank you for your response however, when I run this it still only returns the header of my csv file column

Comment: @Jackie, I have not paying attention to your code a little, you need to change how you split each line. use ```rows.split()``` instead of ```(rows.split(',')[0])```. I have fix the code above